# If the range of $y = f(x)$ is $-1\leq y\leq 2$, what is the range of $y = 1/f(x)$

Tags: functions

If the range of $y = f(x)$ is $-1\leq y\leq 2$, what is the range of $y = 1/f(x)$

Could someone explain why is it not $-1\leq y\leq 1/2$?

Comment: If $y=1/100000$ then $1/y=100000$.

Comment: When you take the reciprocal in an inequality, you need to flip the inequality signs.

Comment: This question is perfectly good, including the specific point of confusion. Why downvote?

Comment: @Trebor I would not have downvoted the question.  However, the OP apparently made no effort to show work that considers what happens when $y$ is near $0$.  Here, I (subjectively) feel that it depends on the (*unstated*) Math background of the OP (i.e. original poster) as to whether it is reasonable to expect that such work would be shown.

Answer (score 1):

When you take the reciprocal of the sides of this inequality, you need to flip the inequality signs. Because $y = \frac{1}{f(x)}$ is undefined when $f(x) = 0$ and $y$ is not monotonic over it's entire domain, let's seperate the inequality into two inequalities as following:
\begin{align}
\tag{1}
0 > f(x)\geq -1
\newline 
\tag{2}
0 < f(x) \leq 2
\end{align}

Then, from $(1)$ and $(2)$, you get:
\begin{align}
\tag{3}
\frac{1}{f(x)}\leq-1
\newline
\tag{4}
\frac{1}{f(x)}\geq \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

We can say that the range of $y = \frac{1}{f(x)}$ is $(-\infty,-1] \cup [\frac{1}{2},\infty)$

Note: A way you can intuitively see this is for $-1\leq f(x)<0$, as $f(x)$ get closer to zero, the value of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ gets bigger, starting from $-1$. You can use a similar method to see for $0<f(x)\leq 2$, this time the value of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ will get closer to $1/2$ when the value of $f(x)$ gets closer to $2$, and the value of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ will approach $\infty$ while $f(x)$ approaches $0$.

Comment: I don't think "flipping inequality when taking reciprocals" is true in general. For example, $-1<y<2$ doesn't imply $-1>\frac{1}{y}>1/2$

Comment: The inequality you wrote is wrong, as $-1 > \frac{1}{y}$ and $\frac{1}{y}>\frac{1}{2}$ give different and not intersecting solutions for $\frac{1}{y}$. Plus, $\frac{1}{2} > -1$

Comment: Yes exactly. That was my point

Comment: $a>b \Rightarrow \frac{1}{a}<\frac{1}{b}$ if and only if $a,b \in (-\infty,0) or (0,\infty)$

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{x} $ is not monotincally decreasing over its entire domain

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my answer, is it better now?

Comment: Yes, but you need to split the inequality into 2 parts not because the function is undefined at $x=0$ but because it is not monitic over its entire domain. You can define f(0)=0 and you'd still need to split it into 2 parts

Comment: Ok, I've edited it again. Thank you!

Comment: In general, if $f$ is monotically decreasing over $I$, then for any $a,b\in I $ where $a<b$, $f(a)>f(b)$. But for $f(x)=1/x$, this is only true if $I=(-\infty,0)$ or $ I=(0,\infty)$

Answer (score 0):

1. [image]

   Using $f(x)=x$ (the red line) as an example, notice that  its
   reciprocal (the blue curve) has a greater absolute value than itself
   on $(-1,1).$

   Also, notice that its reciprocal gets infinitely large on the right
   side of $0$ and infinitely small on the left side of $0.$

   This shows why the reciprocal of a function with range $[-1,2]$
   cannot possibly lie within $[-1,\frac12].$
2. In general, when applying a decreasing function to an inequality and flipping its inequality signs, the new inequality is equivalent to the original one.

   Notice that $\displaystyle\frac1x$ is a decreasing function if and only if its domain lies on either side of the $y$-axis. So, the inequality $$a\leq f(x)\leq b$$ is equivalent to $$\frac1a\geq \frac1{f(x)}\geq \frac1b$$ if and only only $a$ and $b$ have the same sign.

Comment: $1/x$ is NOT increasing in any interval in its domain

Comment: @VulgarMechanick I've corrected the silly mistake. Care to reverse the downvote?

Answer (score -1):

Your question is equivalent to finding the range of $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ over the domain [-1,2]. Notice that the function is not defined at $x=0$ so we instead find its domain over $[-1,0)\cup(0,2]$.

Now, the $g(x)$ is strictly decreasing over the intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ which means that

1. for any $a,b\in (-\infty,0)$  where $a<b$, $g(a)>g(b)$
2. for any $c,d\in (0,\infty)$  where $c<d$, $g(c)>g(d)$

You can see this by either plotting $g(x)=1/x$ , or by differentiating to find $g'(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2}<0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}≠0$

So for $$0<x≤2$$
$$g(0)>g(x)≥g(2)$$
Αs stated before, $g(0)$ is not defined, but what you can do is see that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=+\infty$$
so , roughly speaking, $$+\infty>g(x)≥\frac{1}{2} $$
$$\Rightarrow \text{range of g over }(0,2]=\left[\frac{1}{2},\infty \right)$$

Similarly,for $$-1≤x<0$$
$$g(-1)≥g(x)>g(0)$$
and again,$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=-\infty$$
so , roughly speaking, $$-1≥g(x)>-\infty $$
$$\Rightarrow \text{range of g over }[-1,0)=\left(-\infty,-1\right]$$

**Note:** The reason we had to divide the domain into 2 parts was to ensure that the upper and lower bounds lay in a domain in which the function was strictly decreasing.

You can use this strategy to solve many inequalities in general. For example, since $\ln(x)$ and $e^x$ are monotically increasing over their entire domains, you can take natural logs/exponentials of both sides while preserving the inequality. Similarly, if sides of the inequality are both positive or  both negative, you can square with both while preserving the inequality, as $x^2$ is strictly increasing over $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Formatting tip:  Type `$\ln x$` to produce $\ln x$.  Two typos in the last paragraph:  you meant to write natural logs rather than natural longs and strictly increasing rather than striclty increasing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make a note of that.